# FX Data - analyse intraday data

Tags: python, pandas

I've just found pandas and python recently. I've gone through Wes' book, plus I've repeatedly trawled through the pandas tagged questions here at SO to glean the answer to this question. So I have tried... My meagre programming intelligence is shining through unfortunately ;)

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I have Intraday FX data (hourly) which I am trying to do some pretty simple analysis on. I am looking to test how often the price tests the daily open level and either rejects it or passes through it.

That seems simple to me.... I'm just lost in bringing all the components together to get to a final complete solution.

In psuedocode here is what I am trying to achieve:

- read data in via read_csv
- calculate each daily open level (using at_time?)
- for all hourly candles

  - test if the candle low falls below the daily open level
  - test if the close of the candle is above the daily open level

If someone could please point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it. I'm at the point where I'm going to give up on this. I feel the answer should be really simple, but I'm lost at the moment

Here is the data I've been working with:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data/GBPUSD60.csv', 
                names=['Date','Time','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume'],
                parse_dates={'Timestamp': ['Date', 'Time']},
                index_col=['Timestamp'])

                # Get rid of the volume
                del data['Volume']
```

resulting DF:

```
                     Open    High    Low     Close   
Timestamp                   
2012-11-14 04:00:00  1.58766 1.58890 1.58749 1.58877      
2012-11-14 05:00:00  1.58874 1.58887 1.58819 1.58849      
2012-11-14 06:00:00  1.58849 1.58921 1.58831 1.58890      
2012-11-14 07:00:00  1.58890 1.58895 1.58811 1.58876      
2012-11-14 08:00:00  1.58874 1.58934 1.58841 1.58849
```

I'm assuming I need to go about this one of two ways:

- either group the data by day and loop through the rows to test the intraday candles.
- Secondly, I could use the df.apply function and generate a function to test the candles

The problem with either approach is that I get into all sorts of trouble trying to access the fields I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pseudo code was spot on. Here's the semantics

Step 1: Make a date column

```
df['date'] = [i.date() for i in df.index]
```

Step 2: Get the open per day (assuming opening price is the open column on first candle of the day)

```
df['dailyOpen'] = df.groupby('date').open.transform(lambda s: s[0])
```

Step 3: Comparison

```
df['flag'] = (df.low < df.dailyOpen) & (df.close > df.dailyOpen)
```

If you want the number of times in a day the above happens, this should work

```
res = df.groupby('date').flag.sum()
```

Comment: Thanks. Point taken on the date() method. Updated answer. Attribute access seems to work without problems for me

Comment: +1 now.  Turns out the reason attribute access wasn't working was because my columns were the same as the OP's, namely uppercase. :^)

Comment: Fantastic - thanks for that! 

I've been banging my head against a wall on this for a while. 

Would I be able to essentially do he same thing for weekly open etc? I'd have to resample the data forst into weekly ohlc.

Thanks again!

Comment: Converting hourly ohlc to weekly ohlc might take a little bit of coaxing as you would have to sample open,high,low,close differently ('how' parameter of resample)